# Asp.Net Mvc Receive Mail Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, email, smtp

I have one problem about receive email. Now, I write Contact page in my project. If some user wanna send email, he/she write **email adress** and **message** and click Send buttom. My code send from berdankoca@gmail.com to berdankoca@gmail.com. I couldn't understand why it didn't sent from **email area** to **berdankoca@gmail.com**

### My Code

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult About(string name, string email, string message)
    {
        MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
        mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(email);
        mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress("berdankoca@gmail.com"));

        mailMessage.Subject = "Deneme";
        mailMessage.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default;
        mailMessage.Body = message;
        mailMessage.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default;

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("berdankoca@gmail.com", "xxxx");
        client.EnableSsl = true;

        client.Send(mailMessage);

        return View();
    }
```

I hope I can explain. Thanks for all replies.

Comment: because you can't (lets keep it simple) send emails from other people in their name. You can send emails from your accounts (for which you have the appropriate credentials), I can send emails from mine. In your situation, maybe record the users email as text in the email body?

Comment: I got it. I thought I can do it but u are rigth. I don't record anything about email. Now I decide to write user email in email body.